# How to simulate conditional hugging priorities in AutoLayout?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have a UIView that contains a multiline UILabel and a UIImageView. The imageView is a square that is a specific height and width and is centered vertically in the cell, while the label is constrained to the top of the view. Here's a little illustration:

[image]

I want to be able to make the parent view expandable based on either the UILabel or the UIImageView, based on which one has the bigger height. How would I go about doing this (in Storyboard)?

Comment: Please check

http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would set a bottom and top constraint for both the label and image view at a high priority. Set the constant equal to the amount of padding you'd want.

Then, on the parent view, you'll want to add a height constraint with a lower priority than the top/bottom constraints of the label and image.

That way, you guarantee padding between the label/image and their superview, which will force the superview to expand its height since its priority is lower than that of the padding.